# UItableview loading inside content slow ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, contacts

I have an app in which I am filtering the duplicate contacts I have achieved the functionality but the problem is it is quick for few contacts as the contacts are more loading also becomes slow.
Below is the block of code which I am using

```
-(void)loadDuplicateContacts{


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        [addressBook loadContacts:^(NSArray<APContact *> * _Nullable contacts, NSError * _Nullable error) {

            NSMutableArray *duplucateDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            duplucateDataArray = [contacts mutableCopy];
            duplicateContactsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            duplicateContactsDictinary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            self.dictionaryKeys = [NSArray new];
            for (APContact *contact in duplucateDataArray) {
                NSMutableArray *countArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                [duplucateDataArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(APContact *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
                 {

                     if ([JustNumber([obj.phones[0] number]) isEqualToString:JustNumber([contact.phones[0] number])])
                     {

                         [countArray addObject:contact.name.compositeName];

                     }
                 }];

                if (countArray.count > 1) {

                    if (duplicateContactsDictinary[JustNumber([contact.phones[0] number])]) {
                        NSMutableArray  *retriveArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                        retriveArray = [duplicateContactsDictinary objectForKey:JustNumber([contact.phones[0] number])];
                        [retriveArray addObject:contact];
                        [duplicateContactsDictinary setObject:retriveArray forKey:JustNumber([contact.phones[0] number])];

                    }else{
                        NSMutableArray *contactCreationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                        [contactCreationArray addObject:contact];
                        [duplicateContactsDictinary setObject:contactCreationArray forKey:JustNumber([contact.phones[0] number])];

                    }
                    [duplicateContactsArray addObject:contact];

                }

            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            });

        }];
    });

}
```

Any suggestions would be more helpful

Comment: If dispatch_async some times it takes time to load the View. Because your execution code is in queue on main thread. So sometimes it happens. Use "NSPredicate" concept to remove duplicates. It is faster than enumeration.

Comment: how use predicate to filter the property inside object ?  as you can see APConatcts is my object it has phones property and i don't want to remove conatcts i want all duplicate contacts to show.